# Update ehcache periodically from database using javathread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, caching, ehcache

I have continuously running web application in which users constantly adding data. I want to update my Ehcache(Configuration provided below) periodically using Java thread. I'm bit confused how I should write my threading code to update Ehcache periodically. Please suggest me, my existing code and configuration provided below:-

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
<cache name="allUserProfileMap" maxElementsInMemory="1000" maxElementsOnDisk="100000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" />
</ehcache>
```

CacheRoomTemplate.java

```
public class CacheRoomTemplate implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1025054737473362397L;
private CacheRoomTemplate storageTemplate;  

public void setDelegate(CacheRoomTemplate storageDelegate) {
    this.storageTemplate = storageDelegate;
}   

/*
 * All UserInfo
 */
public static Map<Integer, Profile> allUserProfileMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Profile>();

@Cacheable(cacheName = "allUserProfileMap")
public Profile getAllUserProfileMap(Integer userId) {
    logger.debug("== find AllUserProfileMap by emailId={}", userId);
    if(storageTemplate != null)
        storageTemplate.getAllUserProfileMap(userId);
    return allUserProfileMap.get(userId);
}

@Cacheable(cacheName = "allUserProfileMap")
public Profile removeUserFromAllUserProfileMap(Integer userId) {
    logger.debug("== remove UserId by EmailId={}", userId);
    if(storageTemplate != null)
        storageTemplate.removeUserFromAllUserProfileMap(userId);
    return allUserProfileMap.remove(userId);
}

@Cacheable(cacheName = "allUserProfileMap")
public Set<Profile> findAllUserProfileMap() {
    Collection<Integer> keys = allUserProfileMap.keySet();
    Set<Profile> profileSet = new HashSet<Profile>();
    synchronized (profileSet) {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            profileSet.add(getAllUserProfileMap(iterator.next()));
        }
    }
    logger.debug("== got all registered email Ids from providers, size={}", profileSet.size());
    if(storageTemplate != null)
        storageTemplate.findAllCacheLoggedInIds();
    return profileSet;
}


@TriggersRemove(cacheName = "allUserProfileMap", when = When.AFTER_METHOD_INVOCATION, removeAll = true)
public void addAllUserProfileMap(Integer userId, Profile profile) {
    allUserProfileMap.put(userId, profile);
    logger.debug("== added a AllUserProfileMap with id={}", userId);
    if(storageTemplate != null)
        storageTemplate.addAllUserProfileMap(userId, profile);
}
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">
<ehcache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="cache" class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache" factory-bean="cacheManager" factory-method="getCache">
    <constructor-arg value="myCache"/>
</bean>
```

Anybody can help me to write the code that could query database and update cache periodically using multithreading.